# Is there any windows functions to get all OU(Organizational Unit) name using the domainName?

Tags: c++, winapi, dns, active-directory, window

i want to get all OU name using the domain name.

But i cant use C#,i want it from any windows functions or C++.

Can anyone tell about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use e.g. ADSI ADO provider for that.

[Here's the sample for VBScript](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/187529). You can easily port the code into C++, just use the [#import directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675103%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @ Soonts : that code also need OU name for execute.what i actually need is,if i give domain name i want to know or list all OU name under the domain.can u got my point?

Comment: @SanjuMonu that article describes a generic way you to find anything by any attributes. To find all OUs in your.domain.local, the search string will be "<LDAP://dc=your,dc=domain,dc=local>,(objectClass=organizationalUnit);ADsPath,objectClass;subtree"

Comment: @ Soonts : I dont know the ADspath also,i have only username,password,and domain name.now how can i achieve this.

Comment: If you know the domain DNS name "your.domain.local" then you know the ADs path which is "dc=your,dc=domain,dc=local". If you only know pre-windows 2000 domain name a.k.a. domain NetBIOS name, then you could first search for the domain in the global catalog, see here http://www.selfadsi.org/global-catalog-ldap-search.htm the last sample "GC Search when the own domain name / forest is unknown".

Comment: @ Soonts: can u give any c++ Code.

Comment: @SanjuMonu see my link above "#import directive".